# Webpack module federation using multiple git repos. Is there an example?

Tags: git, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I am finding my way in the world of [Webpack 5 module federation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/). There is a lot of good material and examples, like [this](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples) and [this](https://stackblitz.com/github/webpack/webpack.js.org/tree/master/examples/module-federation).

However, all examples I found are built inside single Git repos, often using [npm workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) and/or nested package.json files.

Since I am going to implement module federation among multiple Git repositories, I'd like to see an example that does exactly that. Has anyone spotted such example?

I assume that the job is done in the definition of the remotes; I have seen some cases where the remote is defined through an URL, but in my case all remotes will be known at build time, so I guess an URL is overkill. Am I right?

Comment: I am also looking for the same. do you have any example explaining how to achieve module federation using multiple Git repositories?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you don't have to mention the URL. I did not find any example handy but I tried following the same mono-repo example across two different repos. I did this:

On the micro-frontend app:
output: { publicPath: '../[app-name]' }

On the shell-app:
I used ***loadRemoteModule***  from '@angular-architects/module-federation'; just have to mention ***remoteEntry*** as the ***publicpath*** that you configured on MFE app so that it gets the remoteentry from there.

Comment: This looks like a solution for Angular sites. I'd love to see something generic. Relevant answer, though... (upvoted :-)

Comment: It never mentions angular, I believe it is a generic solution already.

Comment: @DavidNoreña - It _is_ an Angular solution. Check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-architects/module-federation) out.

Comment: same code will work for multiple frontend frameworks that is the reason I say it is generic already.